# Would like to display current price for iOS app A within app B in user's currency. Possible?

Tags: ios, appdata

In answer to an earlier question, it was pointed out that using this form of lookup -- http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=422876559 -- retrieves all of the info about the corresponding app from the app store. I would like to be able to display the current price of app B within app A. I would like to do it in the currency of the user. I know how to do this if I'm getting in-app product info using StoreKit, but, for the json data returned by the lookup, I wonder if the price is automatically in the user's currency and if there's a way to automatically display it properly (with euro sign or whatever). Anybody know?

Comment: try it and see what the JSON returns...

Comment: If you manage to find out where the user of app A is, you can specify a two-letter country code to get localised prices. E.g. http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=422876559&country=de However, the default value is US.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful to know.